# Computing the localization of a module at a maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $R=k[x]$.  For $\lambda_0 \in k$, what is the localization of the $R$-module $$M=\bigoplus_{\lambda \in k} k[x]/(x-\lambda)$$ at the maximal ideal $(x-\lambda_0)$?

My motivation is in investigating an example of a quasi-coherent sheaf on an affine scheme whose support is not closed.  I've found it stated that the support of the quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{A}_k^1}$-module $\widetilde{M}$ is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}_k^1$, but I am running into problems when trying to compute the stalks of this sheaf.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Localization commutes with direct sums and taking quotients. Does that simplify things at all for you?

Comment: I do know this, but I am still having trouble seeing what I get from it.  I realize that this is probably a very basic commutative algebra question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localization commutes with direct sums, so the problem is to determine $k[x]/(x - \lambda)$ localized at $(x - \lambda_0)$. If $\lambda \neq \lambda_0$ then one of the elements we'll try to invert is $x - \lambda$, so what happens then? If $\lambda = \lambda_0$ then something similarly silly will happen, although the result will be different. You could also do this by commuting the quotient and the localization.

For this to really display a counterexample, we should also check the generic point. It's also worth thinking about why we can't use $\prod$ instead of $\bigoplus$.

Comment: The localization of $k[x]/(x-\lambda)$ at $(x-\lambda_0)$ is zero for $\lambda \neq \lambda_0$, and the ring itself if $\lambda=\lambda_0$.  Is this statement correct?

Comment: So the stalk of $\widetilde{M}$ at all closed points is nonzero, but it is zero at the generic point? What if we consider just varieties? Is the stronger statement, "the support of a _quasi_-coherent sheaf is closed" true?

Comment: I guess we could modify this example to get a quasi-coherent sheaf supported at the integers, say, which is not a closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^1$ in the Zariski topology. Is that a counterexample?

Comment: I think you finished it off just fine. $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a variety and $\widetilde{M}$ is quasicoherent so I'm not sure what you're asking in the second comment. What is true, and a very good exercise, is that the support of a finite type quasicoherent sheaf is closed. And I think you're right that this works for $\mathbb{Z}$ too. For simple statements, $k[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ usually exhibit the same phenomena.

Comment: The sheaf $\widetilde{M}$ on the scheme $\mathrm{Spec} \, R$ in the statement of the question is supported away from the generic point, which isn't a closed set, but the variety $\mathbb{A}^1$ (in the classical sense) doesn't have a generic point. So using the same $\widetilde{M}$ wouldn't be a counterexample because the support would be the whole $\mathbb{A}^1$, right?